# XSLT split single xml into multiple xmls preserving parent elements

Tags: xml, xslt, split, xslt-2.0

I am trying to split a huge xml(around 300MB) into smaller files based on a repeated child element.

Example below to illustrate the scenario

*input.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
   <b></b>
   <bb></bb>
   <bbb>
        <c>
            <d id="1">
                <x></x>
                <y></y>
            </d>
            <d id="2">
                <x></x>
                <y></y>
            </d>
            <d id="3">
                <x></x>
                <y></y>
            </d>
        </c>
    </bbb>
    <e></e>
    <f></f>
</a>
```

As mentioned above this has a repeated child element . Based on this element, separate output files are expected by keeping its parent elements and attributes intact.

Expected output *out_1_a.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
   <b></b>
   <bb></bb>
   <bbb>
        <c>
            <d id="1">
                <x></x>
                <y></y>
            </d>
        </c>
    </bbb>
    <e></e>
    <f></f>
</a>
```

Expected output *out_2_a.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
   <b></b>
   <bb></bb>
   <bbb>
        <c>
            <d id="2">
                <x></x>
                <y></y>
            </d>
        </c>
    </bbb>
    <e></e>
    <f></f>
</a>
```

Expected output *out_3_a.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
   <b></b>
   <bb></bb>
   <bbb>
        <c>
            <d id="3">
                <x></x>
                <y></y>
            </d>
        </c>
    </bbb>
    <e></e>
    <f></f>
</a>
```

My xsl - sample.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="a/bbb/c/d">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="out_{$i}_a.xml">
    <a>
        <b></b>
        <bb></bb>
        <bbb>
            <c>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../@* | ." />
            </c>
        </bbb>
        <e></e>
        <f></f>
    </a>
    </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works ok and I get the output that I desire.
However, I am sure there is a better way to achieve this than hardcoding those parent elements like a, b, bb etc. Also in some cases these parent elements contains attributes and they are dynamic. So hardcoding is something I want to avoid. Any better way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<xsl:template match="d">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="generate-id()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="outputposition"><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::d)+1"></xsl:value-of></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="out_{$outputposition}_a.xml" indent="yes">
        <xsl:call-template name="spilit">
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="$name"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="element" select="root()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="spilit">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:param name="element"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$element[descendant-or-self::d[generate-id() eq $name]]">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="self::d[generate-id() = $name]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"></xsl:copy-of>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"></xsl:copy-of>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::*"/>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:call-template name="spilit">
                        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="$name"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="element" select="child::*[descendant-or-self::d[generate-id() eq $name]]"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The output files getting generated have a different structure than desired by the OP. The copying of `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling` isn't at the right place.

Comment: Thanks @LingamurthyCS, Now i have updated the script

Comment: Hi Rupesh, This works perfectly to my scenario. Thanks.
However, one question related to matching the id attribute of element d. If there are no atttributes in the element d, then is there a way to split it?

Comment: Hi A.K., for your question about where no attribute, I have edit the answer. now this work if attribute is not available

Comment: Thanks @Rupesh once again also thanks for enlightening me the use of generate-id.
If I were to delete one of the element in following-sibling say e, then what should I match with?

Comment: @Rupesh: Nevermind. I was able to use <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*[not(self::e)]"/>
And works fine.

Comment: Very nice program to split XML content, plus one.

Answer (score 1):

The below **XSLT-2.0** solution should do this job easily:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="createDoc">
        <xsl:param name="id"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- apply-templates to the attributes and, the desired 'd' child element or all children elements -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, if(node()[generate-id() = $id]) then node()[generate-id() = $id] else node()" mode="createDoc">
                <xsl:with-param name="id" select="$id"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to create documents per `d` element -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="a/bbb/c/d">
            <xsl:result-document href="out_{@id}_a.xml">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="root(.)" mode="createDoc">
                    <!-- pass the id of the desired element to be copied omitting its siblings-->
                    <xsl:with-param name="id" select="generate-id()"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The second template creates a document per `d` element by passing the `generate-id()` of the matched element to the recursive template(the first template).

The first template, recursively copies all elements. Also, it uses an `xsl:if` to copy only the desired `d` element by its `generate-id()` and omitting other siblings.